# Accessing target file on remote system with chains of symbolic links

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, filesystems, symlink

I am creating a chain of symbolic links (up to [max](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee381413%28v=prot.10%29.aspx), which is 64 chains) on a remote target file on vista. While connecting a new symlink to this chain, I am verifying whether I am able to open target file or not with newly added symlink. What I see is, addition of 20 symlinks in a chain works fine, but when I add the 21st symlink to the chain and try to open the target file with this new chain I get an error:

```
error 1921 (The name of the file cannot be resolved by the system).
```

The same error I see when I try to open that symlink via notepad but when I open that symlink with command prompt, target file opens just fine, so it seems link is connected but somehow while opening the same symlink with `CreateFile winapi` with `OpenExisting` flag is returning 1921 error. I am not sure why is that behavior.

It would be great help if someone help me through this issue.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: what use is a 20 symlinks long chain ?

Comment: There is one use case based on some DB/ system req, which is totally irrelevant the question. I dont need a chain of 64 but i do need a chain long enough to satisfy the requirement.

Comment: Your question mentions the file system but the link you gave mentions the registry.

Comment: @Luke: In link, the para which i want you to read is :
"The server MUST support recursive symbolic links. If the target of a symbolic link has a KEYTYPE of symbolic link, then the server MUST follow the symbolic link to the next target key. The server MUST link the maximum depth of a chain of symbolic links, which is "64"."

This question is not at all related to registry. 

Symbolic concept is related to filesystem.

Comment: That documentation is specifically talking about symbolic links in the registry, not the file system.  The file system probably has similar considerations, but you can't infer that from documentation about the registry.